# write/read float array in java fast way

Tags: java, android, arrays, io, floating-point

I am trying to write and read float array(pretty large actually, 640*480) in android devices with java codes.
like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405836/write-a-float-array-to-file-in-java)

```
    DataOutputStream out = ...;
for (int i=0; i<floatarray.length; ++i)
    out.writeFloat(floatarray[i]);
```

is very slow and I have try it in this.

WRITE:

```
            float[] test=new float[3];
        test[0]=1.0f;
        test[1]=1.2f;
        test[2]=1.5f;
        //long timeBeforeWrite = System.nanoTime();
        try {
            BufferedOutputStream  dataOut = new BufferedOutputStream (
                    new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/Dual/demo.bin"));

            byte buf[]=new byte[4*test.length];

            long timeBeforeWrite = System.nanoTime();

            for (int i=0; i<test.length; ++i)
            {
                int val = Float.floatToRawIntBits(test[i]);
                buf[4 * i] = (byte) (val >> 24);
                buf[4 * i + 1] = (byte) (val >> 16) ;
                buf[4 * i + 2] = (byte) (val >> 8);
                buf[4 * i + 3] = (byte) (val);
            }



            dataOut.write(buf);

            long ct_write = System.nanoTime();
            long offset_write = ct_write - timeBeforeWrite;
            float mOffsetInMs_write = (float)(offset_write)/1000000;
            Log.e("ETA", "write float[]  " + Float.toString(mOffsetInMs_write));

            dataOut.flush();
            dataOut.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

READ：

```
            float[] read=new float[3];

        try{
            BufferedInputStream  dataIn=new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/Dual/demo.txt"));
            byte buf[]=new byte[4*read.length];
            long timeBeforeWrite = System.nanoTime();

            dataIn.read(buf);

            for (int i=0; i<read.length; ++i)
            {
                    int val;
val = buf[4 * i] << 24;
                    val += buf[4 * i + 1] << 16;
                    val += buf[4 * i + 2] << 8;
                    val += buf[4 * i + 3];

                read[i]=Float.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString(val));

                //int val = Float.floatToRawIntBits(disparityMap[i]);

            }

            long ct_write = System.nanoTime();
            long offset_write = ct_write - timeBeforeWrite;
            float mOffsetInMs_write = (float)(offset_write)/1000000;
            Log.e("ETA", "read float[]  " + Float.toString(mOffsetInMs_write));

            dataIn.close();

        }catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

things read back is pretty strange floating point values, and what's wrong with this?BTW, read back runs pretty slow, don't know why.
 Or any other good idea for fast read/write float array?

Thanks!

//Thanks to Larry, I have try bytebuffer.asfloatbuffer() ways like:

```
//WRITE
    float[] test = new float[3];
    test[0]=1.1f;
    test[1]=1.2f;
    test[2]=1.5f;
    try{
        RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile("/sdcard/demo.data", "rw");
        FileChannel outChannel = aFile.getChannel();

        //one float 3 bytes
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(12);
        buf.clear();
        buf.asFloatBuffer().put(test);

        //while(buf.hasRemaining()) 
        {
            outChannel.write(buf);
        }

        outChannel.close();

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    //READ
    float[] readback=new float[3];
    try{


        RandomAccessFile rFile = new RandomAccessFile("/sdcard/demo.data", "rw");
        FileChannel inChannel = rFile.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buf_in = ByteBuffer.allocate(12);
        buf_in.clear();

        inChannel.read(buf_in);

        buf_in.asFloatBuffer().get(readback);

        inChannel.close();

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

and the program crashes in `buf_in.asFloatBuffer().get(readback);`
any idea and is there goods ways to goes in and debug inside in java, Sorry completely new in java world. Thanks again

Comment: I've the same problem as you... "buf_in.asFloatBuffer().get(readback);" crashes... Have you solved the problem?

Comment: The problem missing here is that the position of the buffer is wrong. You need to call position(0) on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `FileChannel` for your file access and a `ByteBuffer` for the data.  You can put the data into the `ByteBuffer` using the `ByteBuffer.putFloat()` methods and write it out with `FileChannel.write()`.  When you read it back, you can call `FileChannel.read()` to get a ByteBuffer representing the data, then call `ByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer()` to get a `FloatBuffer` representing the data which can then be used to get a `float[]`.

Comment: thanks a lot and I have update my problems, read back is not working in buf_in.asFloatBuffer().get(readback); any ideas about this?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Larry, I am just sharing my codes and hopefully it helps someone else.

I just figure it out, we need to rewind to buffers after read/write to file channels. following codes just works, and runs pretty fast.

```
float[] disparity=new float[640*480];

    disparity[1]=1.5f;
    disparity[2]=4.566f;

//WRITE
    try{
        RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile("/sdcard/demo.data", "rw");
        FileChannel outChannel = aFile.getChannel();

        //one float 4 bytes
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4*640*480);
        buf.clear();
        buf.asFloatBuffer().put(disparity);

        //while(buf.hasRemaining()) 
        {
            outChannel.write(buf);
        }

        //outChannel.close();
        buf.rewind();

        float[] out=new float[3];
        buf.asFloatBuffer().get(out);

        outChannel.close();

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    //READ
    float[] readback=new float[640*480];
    try{

        RandomAccessFile rFile = new RandomAccessFile("/sdcard/demo.data", "rw");
        FileChannel inChannel = rFile.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buf_in = ByteBuffer.allocate(640*480*4);
        buf_in.clear();

        inChannel.read(buf_in);

        buf_in.rewind();
        buf_in.asFloatBuffer().get(readback);

        inChannel.close();

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Thanks again.

Comment: You must close the file in a `finally` block or use `try-with-resources`! You are correct about rewinding during read, but not during write. I suggest you do: `try (ByteChannel channel = Files.newByteChannel( path, WRITE, CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING )) { ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(disparity.length * 4); buf.asFloatBuffer().put(disparity); channel.write (buf); }`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a BufferedOutputStream between your DataOutputStream and your FileOutputStream.