# Android ByteBuffer to float conversion return wrong values

Tags: java, android, bytebuffer

I am trying to read txt file using `RandomAccessFile` and `FileChannel` which contains large number of float / integer values, but at after the all conversations using `ByteBuffer` the values which I get as a result are not the same with the ones in txt file. Here is how I am doing it :

```
        RandomAccessFile mRandomFile = new RandomAccessFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Models/vertices.txt", "rw");
        FileChannel mInChannel = mRandomFile.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer mBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(181017 * 4);
        mBuffer.clear();

        mInChannel.read(mBuffer);

        mBuffer.rewind();
        FloatBuffer mFloatBUffer = mBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        mFloatBUffer.get(VERTS);

        mInChannel.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Log.d("", "VALUE: " + VERTS[i]);
        }
```

The values in txt file are presented in this way (they are separated with a new line):

```
-36.122300
-6.356030
-46.876744
-36.122303
-7.448818
-46.876756
-36.122303
-7.448818
81.123221
-36.122300
-6.356030
81.123209
36.817676
-6.356030
-46.876779
36.817676
-7.448818
-46.876779
-36.122303
-7.448818
```

and the values which I am getting in `for` are:

```
VALUE: 1.0187002E-11
VALUE: 2.5930944E-9
VALUE: 6.404289E-10
VALUE: 2.5957827E-6
VALUE: 2.6255839E-6
VALUE: 8.339467E-33
VALUE: 4.1885793E-11
VALUE: 1.0740952E-5
VALUE: 1.0187002E-11
VALUE: 2.5930944E-9
VALUE: 6.513428E-10
VALUE: 1.0383363E-5
VALUE: 4.3914857E-5
VALUE: 8.339467E-33
VALUE: 4.1885793E-11
VALUE: 1.0801023E-5
VALUE: 1.0187002E-11
VALUE: 2.5930944E-9
VALUE: 6.513428E-10
VALUE: 1.0383363E-5
```

Any ideas, suggestions what I am missing here?

Comment: It is a text file, not a file full of floats in binary format. You're using the wrong tools for the job.

Comment: Ok, so the question is, how I should create this binary file full with floats? I've seen some examples with RandomAccessFile using txt files, that's why I tried this option in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android-Developer again, i see you try the binary-file-approach... to do this you must convert your data

Create a **new** Java-Project and use your original methods there to load the the values from a xml/text-file and convert it into floats... (yes, it will take some time then, but it provided valid data...) once you have the data inside your application store your floats into a file named floats.bin (using a FileWriter).

Go then and copy the file floats.bin into your Android Project and try to load it there with your code from above (looks good in my opinion)...

(referring to [Android fastest way of reading big arrays of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845929/android-fastest-way-of-reading-big-arrays-of-variables/25846974#25846974))
after sleeping one night over your problem i think you can

- either distract the user and load the data before you show your models...
- or you can show the model while you are loading - and let the user see your progress and see the model growing with each second....
- or you can split your data into seperate chunks from coarse to fine and load first the coarse data and show it - then you load into background the finer and finer data and add it piece by piece into your model...

Comment: The problem is that the models are not going to be represent to the user, only if he scans a unique image marker which will load the right model. So if user is in front of the marker and opens the application, he have to wait a lot of time to load the models all of them, because the scan - show model should be really fast process...not more than a second.

Comment: ok, then you really have to load the model before showing... i didn't want be impolite when making those suggestion, sorry...  but maybe my hint with having these two projects helps you out a little bit...

Comment: I will try and post an update with the result, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: i would be really glad to see your progress! and i really wish you good luck and much much success!!!

Comment: Just one question i'm having now... have you ever considered to store the whole 3d-model instead of all points of that model?

Comment: Vuforia is reading the model with it's points, I am not doing like this, because I want it that way. And just for the record, it is working now, I am just a little busy to post the solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: wow - i'm really glad that you found y solution, you where having trouble with this for several days!!! *cheers*

Comment: thanks for remembering me and accepting! i hope we can collaborte further sooner or later!!!  good luck and much much success for you and your app!!!

Answer (score 5):

It is a text file, not a random access file. You should be reading with a `BufferedReader`. It´s got a `readLine()` that returns a String, and then you can just go with `Double.valueOf(String)`.

There´s more code here [How to use Buffered Reader in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265693/how-to-use-buffered-reader-in-java)

Comment: I've tried this and it works, but it's too slow for my needs. So i guess I should create another specific file (random-access) to be able to get the data as it is, right?

Comment: I don´t know what you want to achieve with that. If you just want float or double numbers in a file you should create that with a DataOutputStream http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html and read it with a DataInputStream will be the hell out faster than parsing text files. If you want to draw those points on screen, maybe you should move to some out-of-the-box solution such as SVG for 2d gfx or OBJ or 3DS for 3d models.

Comment: I am using Vuforia for showing 3d models, that's why I need the points for drawing. BufferedReader and DataOutputStream are too slow for loading 12 models where everyone of them has 4 files with like 200 000 float / integer values. That's why I am using FileChannel, which opens and read 4 files for less than a second.